# Do not check in the generic list of a item there is

Tags: c#, list

I wish to make a small insurance application.  The application asks your name and then checks if name already exists; if they exist then you get a message this name is already used.

if not then  you will be asked what for insurance do you want and then on the screen you get a message the name is correctly signed up.

and i have a function that lists all my client's names and the kind of insurance as a generic list

I make a generic list and in my function i use foreach so i can print every item in the generic list everything works good but if i add a person to my list and i try back and write the same name i don't get error.

**Question:** Why I don't get a error? what is the problem actually?

Thank you in advance

my code is here under:

```
public static List<string> klantgegevens = new List<string>();

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    retry:

        string naam;
        int verzekeringkeuze;
        string alleklantgegevens;

        Console.WriteLine("wat is u naam");
        naam = Console.ReadLine();

        if (klantgegevens.Contains(naam))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("deze naam bestaat al");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("kies u soort verzekering: 1-auto,2-leven,3-woning");
            verzekeringkeuze = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (verzekeringkeuze)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(alleklantgegevens = $"{naam}:auto");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(alleklantgegevens = $"{naam}:leven");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(alleklantgegevens = $"{naam}:woning");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"{naam} werd correct ingeschreven");
            Console.ReadLine();
            alleklantgegevens = $"{naam}:{verzekeringkeuze}";
            klantgegevens.Add(alleklantgegevens);
        }
        Printall();
        goto retry;
 }

 public static void Printall()
 {
     foreach (string gegevens in klantgegevens)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"alle klantgegevens:{gegevens}");
     }
     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

Comment: Question aside, don't use goto - use a while(true) loop. It'll block on the input

Comment: Why do you have a ReadLine in Printall() ?

Comment: You have right but i am accustomed to write that because i can read my data and can see the output but it was not really required.

Comment: I use goto because i find that is a shorter way then write a while loop.And what do you mean with it will block on the input can you explain more please?

Answer (score 3):

No error because you check Contains(naam) not $"{naam}:{verzekeringkeuze}" which is what you put in the list.

Comment: 0


You have right but my verzekeringskeuze is my insurance choice whereby i can have a choice several times but what I want to do is check only on the naam but my list must save all my data. How can i resolve this in this way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: One option is to have a separate list of used names, and when you add the insurance to its list also add the name to its list. Another is to represent the whole data as a Map of name to insurance (HashMap<String, Integer>) and check map.ContainsKey(naam).

Comment: I did the first option before i Ask this but someone they studie say me its not a good idea to to that because its spends more memory and its  not effective but I can try the second method but can you write the second method how  I CAN implent that in c#.thanks in advance

Comment: Oh, C# sure :) In C# a map is a Dictionary, so Dictionary<string, int>. Add like this: myDictionary[naam] = insurance. Check like this: myDictionary.ContainsKey(naam).